# How to use pool-specific functions while multiprocessing with python?

Tags: python, function, selenium, multiprocessing

I'm using selenium and multiprocessing to spawn four different websites, and I want to run functions specific to the website the driver generated.

This is similar to my current code:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from selenium import webdriver

def gh(hosts):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='./chromedriver')
    driver.get(hosts)
    html_source = driver.page_source
        if 'ryan' in html_source:
            print 'ryan'
            doSomethingForRyan()
        elif 'austin' in html_source:
            print 'austin'
            doSomethingForAustin()
        elif 'travis' in html_source:
            print 'travis'
            doSomethingForTravis()
        elif 'levi' in html_source:
            print 'levi'
            doSomethingForLevi()
        else:
            print '--NONE--'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Pool(4)

    hosts = ["http://ryan.com", "https://www.austin.com",    "http://levi.com", "http://travis.com"]
    p.map(gh, hosts)
```

The result I'm getting is something like:
austin
austin
ryan
austin

Comment: Quick terminology primer: you are running 4 workers in one pool.

Comment: How do I run different functions in different pools then?

Comment: As a minimum, try enumerating the results to see if the worker is raising and error:   `for result in p.map(gh, hosts): print(result)`. The worker could return True/False for success/failure and you'd get an exception on fail.

Comment: You have the right idea. You have a function that calls any number of other functions based on a webdriver result. Its one pool (otherwise we would see 4 calls to `Pool(1)`).

Comment: I get the result: None None None None

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT - SOLVED**

Instead of reading from driver.page_source, reading from driver.current_url makes sure that I can run website-specific functions.

```
if 'ryan' in driver.current_url:
    print 'ryan'
    doStuff()
```